# Type 'string | AddressInfo' has no property 'port' and no string index signature

Tags: typescript

In `{ port }` I got error: Type 'string | AddressInfo' has no property 'port' and no string index signature.

How to resolve it?

Code:

```
import * as express from 'express'
const app = express()

app.listen({ port: process.env.PORT })

const { port } = app.address()
```

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",

    "composite": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".."
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "../common" }]
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found solution, it works for me:

```
import * as express from 'express'
import { AddressInfo } from 'net'

const app = express()

app.listen({ port: process.env.PORT })

const { port } = app.address() as AddressInfo
```

Comment: I would add that the reason why this happens is that server returns AddressInfo from address() method when listening on IP Socket. When listening to pipe or Unix domain socket, the return value is a string - https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/net.html#net_server_address 
So it's totally safe to cast it like that in express context.

Answer (score 1):

In the example above it's clear that we should have a port, but if it weren't for some reason, you could use a `typeof` comparision as shown below:

```
import * as express from 'express'
const app = express()

app.listen({ /* some args from config perhaps, and not necessarily "port" */})

const addr = server.address();
const binding = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? `pipe/socket ${addr}`
    : `port ${addr.port}`;
console.log(` Server listening on ${binding}`);
```